# May be constraints not working properly in Xcode

Tags: xcode, layout, autolayout, interface-builder

I gave the constraints for the two buttons which are at top-right and bottom-right, see below which is a screen shot of interface builder in Xcode.

[image]

[image]

[image]

But, in device buttons position changed (both buttons moved to top-left position), see the screen shot of device

[image]

I don't know why they are changing position after running and I did not change any properties programatically. Please let me know if I did anything wrong.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the constraints?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, Sure.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, added screen shots of constraints, please check.